# Cognos output. Issues with MHT and Excel

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I'm new to Cognos 10. Been playing with it since yesterday and having issues with my outputs. I'm working with an active report. Dunno if that's the right one to use, but I haven't used Cognos in 3-4 versions.

First, the only output available is MHT. Is it no longer possible to output to excel or PDF? Especially excel?

Second, I can't open my MHT files. I've tried in excel, IE, and Chrome. All three say Starting, have a loading icon, and just stay that way. Is it trying to pull data from Cognos dynamically? And if so, how do I stop it from doing so?

Thanks!
Eric

Comment: No, you cannot export an active report to a different format. I'd suggest you read up on them to see if you actually want to use one.

Answer (score 2):

If you create an Active Report your sole output format will be MHT.
If you create any other type of report you will see the options to output to a variety of formats, including Excel and PDF.

Active Reports are specifically designed to output as MHT.  They do not pull data dynamically but rather are a series of self-contained web resources.  If it is not loading it likely comes down to whether or not the IE version you're using is supported and/or running in compatibility mode.

Comment: Thank you. I've changed  the compatibility mode and can see the report.

One more question, Active Report is what's created by default by the report studio. How would I go about just creating a vanilla report that I can export more easily?

Comment: When you create a new report in Report Studio, you have a variety of report types to select from, including Blank, List, Crosstab, Chart, etc... There's a bunch - active reports are selected as a "default" since it's shiny and new (at least, that's my assumption).  Just pick another report type when it prompts you for what to create and it will be a "vanilla" report.